# Are there any libraries in Emacs or the wider package system for automatically persisting variables

Tags: variables, history-variables

I have a number of variables that store useful state that would be nice to persist across restarts of Emacs. Are there any libraries that allow this to be done simply so I can avoid a bunch of boilerplate for each variable?

I've considered the customise framework but that implies putting everything in one file and it would be nice to specify a specific state file for a given set of variables so they can easily be blown away when required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `savehist` library provides one option for persisting variable values across sessions. e.g.:

```el
(eval-after-load "savehist"
  '(add-to-list 'savehist-additional-variables 'foo))

(savehist-mode 1)
```

As with `customize`, that's writing everything to a single specific file. But there's no reason why you couldn't leverage this library's functionality by let-binding the relevant vars to save and load specific sets of values.

Answer (score 5):

Load library [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) and use a [***variable-list*** bookmark](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#FunctionSequenceVarlistBookmarks).

A variable-list bookmark saves and restores the values of a set of variables.

Command `bmkp-set-variable-list-bookmark` 
prompts you for the variables to include in the list and then sets the bookmark. Non-interactively, you can use function `bmkp-create-variable-list-bookmark` to create or update a variable-list bookmark.

Command `bmkp-jump-variable-list` (**`C-x j v`**) restores the recorded variable values for the bookmark's buffer. You can call also this function non-interactively, of course, including from your init file.

```el
(bmkp-jump-variable-list BOOKMARK) ; BOOKMARK is a bookmark name or a bookmark
```