# How to permanently save modified variable in emacs config?

Tags: init-file, variables

I have list of words to capitalize automatically

```
(setq auto-capital-words '("Foo" "bar"))
```

I have one more function which adds word at point to this list.

```
(defun add-to-capital-words ()
  "Add words"
 )
```

Now when ever i add words, they will be saved only for that session. When i restart emacs they will be gone.

How do i save those values permanently in config, so that they will be updated on multiple systems also?

Comment: Make it a `defcustom`, and tell Emacs to save it when you quit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs can do this by default, with its `savehist` library.

See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7711/454

Answer (score 1):

So it seems you need some kind of serialization. Take a look at [`save-sexp`](https://github.com/tarsius/save-sexp) package, [available via MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/save-sexp).

Answer (score 0):

Install package

```
M-x package-install RET save-sexp
```

Whenever a variable is modified, save in a seperate file.

```
(setq auto-capital-words '("Foo" "bar"))
(save-sexp-save-setq "~/.emacs.d/variables.el" 'auto-capital-words)
```

To load the variables

```
(load-file ""~/.emacs.d/variables.el")
```